# Prove that a homogeneous function $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ of degree $k$ which is $k$ times differentiable at the origin is a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that a homogeneous function $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ of degree $k$ which is $k$ times differentiable at the origin is a polynomial.

I am having trouble with this question.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: $\tan(y/x)$ is not even continuous at $0.$

Comment: How are you defining your example $f$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: That's right. Sorry. I am still having trouble with the question though.

Comment: A typical trick with homogeneous functions: Look at $g(t)=f(tx_1,tx_2,...,tx_n)=t^kf(x_1,...,x_n)$. Compute $k$ derivatives of $g$ at $t=0$ in two ways; directly in the right-hand side and using chain rule on the left side.